# Button not appearing using angular material while using go to next tab

Tags: css, angular, tabs, angular-material, angular7

I am using `angular material` tab library to display vertical and horizontal tabs. There are 3 horizontal tabs and in 2nd horizontal tab, there are vertical tabs. When I put `Next` button it should go to next horizontal tab. It's working with 1st horizontal tab but in 2nd horizontal tab `Next` button is not appearing.

**Here is: [stackblitz - ngular-material-tabs-inside-tab](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-angular-material-tabs-inside-tab-zj6txm-kxwgnu)**

in **tab-group-basic-example.html in 2nd horizontal tab, I put `Next` button:**

```
<div class="m-10">
   <button (click)="nextTab(2)">Next</button>
</div>
```

in **ts** file:

```
nextTab(index: number): void {
    this.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

Comment: You need to add next button in every tab with +1 of current index of tab

Comment: @Awais yes, but in 2nd horizontal tab there are 3 vertical tabs. So what to do there?

Comment: @Awais when I put next btn and click on that, it goes to next tab but when I click on tab to go previous tab, it doesn't work.

Comment: Well in that case i prefer to use `mat-stepper` rather then `tabs` as your requirement tell us so. check this out https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Comment: @Awais yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is that you want do display something outside of `mat-tab`. Moving the next button inside it does the trick:

```
        <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [label]="tab">
          <div class="m-10" #appenHere></div>
          Contents for {{tab}} tab <br> <br>
          <button (click)="addNewComponent()">
            Append to {{tab}}
          </button>
          <div class="m-10">
            <button (click)="nextTab(2)">Next</button>
          </div>
        </mat-tab>
```

Comment: inside for loop will display with all vertical tabs

Comment: when I put next btn and click on that, it goes to next tab but when I click on tab to go previous tab, it doesn't work.

Comment: cannot see the stackblitz page anymore :/

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-angular-material-tabs-inside-tab-zj6txm-kxwgnu